# Disallow variable overwrite in PHP

Tags: php, variables, overwrite

Is it possible to prevent variables from being overwritten in PHP?  I am making a system that has some reserved variables and I don't want them to be replaced with something else after a certain point.  It is possible? If not, what can I do to approach something close to this?

Some of these vars are instantiated classes so I can't define them as constants.

Comment: How about [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)

Comment: What is doing the replacement? Are you importing variables from untrusted user content? Or is this just about the general concept of protecting yourself against your future self?

Comment: Yes, technically is me defending myself to ruin everything but not only me, because I am not the only one writing the scripts so the master variables may collide at some time.

Comment: I don't feel like typing up a full answer for this, so I'll just say this: avoid global variables! Use classes and proper encapsulation techniques.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198237/whats-the-php-equivalent-of-a-final-variable-in-c) question. Also the information about [constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) in the PHP manual may be helpful.

Comment: he said he cannot use constants, although the link in regards to static protected may be helpful.

Comment: I know, that is why I linked to the other question first. Reading up on constants may still be helpful though. (especially some of the example code on the manual page)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they're called **[constants](http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php)**.

If you cannot use them, assuming you're running the latest PHP version, you can use **[namespaces](http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)**, using namespaces, you can have 2 variables of the same name, on different namespaces. So that you don't have collisions.

Comment: he said he cannot use constants

Comment: Thanks, I took a look in the documentation and namespaces will help me a lot in the future, but unfortunately I'll have to deal with different PHP versions in many servers and I can't assume that all of them can be upgraded to the latest version, so I'll take one of the another options

Answer (score 3):

The best you can do (that I am aware of) in this case is make them private variables inside the class. Then you have to use getters and setters to assign the values, or a construct. That way, someone else's code is less likely to collide with yours.

Comment: static is also an option,. but would have to be the same value across all objects.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to find out how it is the easiest in your situations, as there is no code available at all, but on of the better options would probably be is

1. hide them in a class as private member vars.
2. expose them through getters.

If needed, make them static

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can implement something like frozen state, and if class is frozen, can't be modified:

```
class Test
{
    private $variable;
    private $frozen = false;

    public function freeze() {
        $this->frozen = true;
    }

    public function setVariable($value) {
        if ($this->frozen)
            throw new Exception("...");

        $this->variable = $value;
    }
}
```